# C - accessing a struct from dynamic memory

Tags: struct, malloc

I'm writing a program with struct Record. As I read in records from text in a loop, I assign them to buffer before saving buffer into the array. nRange is just the total number of records being read.

```
Record *storage; 
storage = (Record*)malloc(nRange*sizeof(Record)); 
Record buffer;
storage[i] = buffer;
```

I want to access storage[i] in order to check that the record is being saved to memory, but I can't quite get the syntax. I was trying something like:

```
printf("%d \n", &storage[i].x);
```

But I think this is just giving me the address of the x value of the Record at storage[i]. If anyone could give me the exact syntax I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking things. You just write `storage[i]`, just like when you assigned it.

```
printf("%d \n", storage[i].x);
```

Comment: I tried that before too and it gave me some large negative number....but I double checked my code and I was using the same variable for 2 nested loops and that was throwing me off. Thanks!